# Default format DateTime SQL in Oracle, SQL Server and Firebird

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, firebird

I'm doing a manual `INSERT` where I have to format a `DateTime` value in C#. The resulting string is put into a a SQL query. I need a cross-platform format that can be hendled by **Oracle**, **SQL Server** and **Firebird**.

Example:

> With `yyyy-mm-dd` you save the date correctly without relying on the language of the database.

I need the format not to uncouple from *language* but from *vendor quirks*.

Comment: This is one of the many problems that go away when you use query parameters.

Comment: @DanBracuk I can not use parameters, because I have to reduce the maximum processing

Comment: Parameters generally decrease the processing time because Oracle and SQL Server will cache the INSERT statements if they're parameterized, whereas they'll recompile the statements each time if they're not. I don't know about Firebird. As for a common date format, there really isn't a reliable one. SQL Server is OK with `'2014-09-24'`, but Oracle wants the ANSI standard `DATE '2014-09-24'`. It will take `'2014-09-24'` if that's set as the default date format for the session (instead of the "stock" `dd-mon-rr` format), but relying on the session date format is extremely risky.

Comment: Not using bind parameters for Oracle (for OLTP ) is a huge performance and scalability killer.

Comment: Firebird only caches the instance of the prepared statement handle (it doesn't reuse the plan of the statement for multiple handles), and it supports the SQL standard `DATE'yyyy-MM-dd'` format literal (it will usually also work without the prefix).

Comment: `DATE'yyyy-MM-dd'` should work. Other tricks that come into my mind (encoding a date from year/month/day on the fly or some sly conversions) will only add incompatibility due to DB-specific syntax. But if your conditions allow I'd recommend using parameters anyway. String datetime representation makes sense only when generating a transferrable SQL script.